# Ignore First Character in Regex Match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to ignore the `>` in my regular expression in the beginning.

My regular expression:

```
/(>(.+)(?=<\/a>))/igm
```

Matches the following:

[image]

How do I tell it to ignore the `>` in the beginning?

[Here](http://www.regexr.com/39339) is the regular expression on regexr.com.

Comment: positive lookbehind, though it doesnt work in regexr.com for some reason.

Comment: @EdwardM.B.: the reason is that the lookbehind feature isn't available in Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possible workaround would be to match non `>` characters:

```
[^>]+(?=<\/a>)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/eQ4tG8/1)

Or you take the substring of each of your results in the code itself.

Comment: Thank you! I was using `.splice(1)`, but it said it can't splice from null.  so then I had to add `.toString()`

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
.*?>(\w+)<
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Here you can check a working example:

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vSSgb0oRwpEkJRct)